# Change header of all reports in Odoo v11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, qweb

I want to change all the default Odoo report's header. By not inheriting each and every, is there is any way to do in a single time?

Comment: what you mean by inheriting each one? all you have to do is inherit  `external_layout` if you want to have only one header , but if you want to keep the configuration of layout , background, boxed... etc, inherit `web.external_layout_background`, `web.external_layout_boxed` ...etc they are not a lot, or you want something else?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the settings -> General Settings. And edit the RML header and footer as per your customization